# How do I make LWC datetime input close drop down when enter key is pressed?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I have a `lightning-input` (datetime type) and our users will sometimes type 11:59pm in the time field since the drop down selections are only in 15 minute steps. After they are done typing, the intuitive thing to do will be to hit the enter key which would ideally close the drop down and keep what they have typed. However, what actually happens is that the time is changed to become whatever selection from the drop down is currently in focus, thus overriding whatever the user has typed.

I have tried to capture the enter key press with `handleKeyUp` and preventing default but it does not seem to work

**HTML:**

```
<lightning-input 
  label="Commission start date" 
  type="datetime" 
  value={commissionStartDate} 
  onchange={handleDateFieldChange}
  onkeyup={handleKeyUp}>
</lightning-input>
```

**Controller:**

```
handleKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you just tab out instead of hitting enter, it should work the way you want.